# How to change metadata for solana nft collection on phantom wallet for candy machine

Tags: metadata, solana, nft, metaplex

i recently uploaded my collection to mainnet
its called Not Crypto Punks
and in phantom wallet it says collection nft

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your using a Candymachine and it has minted a default Collection NFT for you which has the default name of 'Collection NFT'.

If you look at one of your NFT mints on https://solscan.io/ and head over to the metadata section, within the metadata there will be a collection address which you need to copy.

If you take the collection address and head over to https://sol-tools.tonyboyle.io then put your collection Address into the update NFT section of the site it will allow you to update this NFT with all the details of your collection such as name, image, and description etc... You do not need to worry about attributes or anything else.

This can also be updated anytime at a later date.

You'll need to have the wallet used to create the candymachine in Phantom (or other supported wallet) to be able to update the NFT though.

Make sure it is the collection NFT you are editing and not a normal minted NFT from your collection as well.

If you are unsure of this process feel free to drop into the Metaplex Discord server and we can help you there too :)

**A bit about the collection NFT**

The Collection NFT is just a normal NFT which is used as the album cover/art peiece of your collection. You do not sell or give this NFT to anyone else as it represents your NFT's on the Solana blockchain and to markets such as Magic Eden and OpenSea, and to wallets such as Phantom and SolFlare.

Each NFT minted from your candymachine will point to this NFT and be used as a way to group everything together.

Editing the collection NFT will change the image, name, and description places such as ME and OS, and other places like wallets view you collection.